# I cannot Install APP in iOS

Tags: ios, flash-builder, itunes

I compiled the version of my application, when I try to sync iPhone says:

**Sync iTunes
The installation of "APP" failed**

I use Flash Builder 4.5, Adobe AIR 2.6 and Iphone 4 with iOS 6.1.3

What problem? the same Version to Android is very functional...

Comment: Do you have a valid code signature on the device, and are you sure that the app is built correctly (correct architecture, correct SDK, etc).

Comment: Try to check the certificate and profile which you are using to create IPA.

Comment: If your problem is solved then please accept the answer.

Comment: code is correctly, the problem is the certificate or provision file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen these errors when the device's UDID was not part of the distribution (ad hoc) profile. Did you add this iPhone to the distribution profile in itunes connect?

Comment: Thanks, before I tried to generate test provision, now I tried to generate distribution provision selecting one of my devices and it worked!

Comment: I can´t understand, the ask are solved, why my reputation -1?